# Sorting a dictionary by value when the values are large float numbers (tried lambda and itemgetter but didn't get proper result)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a csv file with people's names and averages as below:

```
mandana,7.5
hamid,6.066666666666666
sina,11.285714285714286
sara,9.75
soheila,7.833333333333333
ali,5.0
sarvin,11.375
```

I want to sort it by the averages and write it into another file. I've tried lambda and itemgetter but I didn't get the proper result. Here is my code:

```
def calculate_sorted_averages(file1, file2):
with open (r'C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Python with Jadi\file1.csv', 'r') as f1:
    reader=csv.reader(f1)
    d={}
    for row in reader:
        name=row[0]
        average=row[1]
        d[name]=average
    sorted_dict=OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
    with open (r'C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Python with Jadi\file2.csv', 'w', newline='') as f2:
        for key in sorted_dict.keys():
            writer=csv.writer(f2)
            writer.writerow([key,sorted_dict[key]])
```

And here is my output:

```
sara,9.75
soheila,7.833333333333333
mandana,7.5
hamid,6.066666666666666
ali,5.0
sarvin,11.375
sina,11.285714285714286
```

As you can see it is not sorted. I've tried also lambda and it didn't work. I'm now frustrated and don't know what to do. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Parse the number from String to float before sorting.

Comment: Minor side-note: If you're guaranteed exactly two items per line, just do `for name, average in reader:` and let Python do the unpacking for you. There's no benefit (and some cost) to iterating the rows then unpacking them one-by-one when the rows are all fixed length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your result because you're sorting lexicographically (comparing your floats as strings) instead of sorting by their numeric value.

All you're missing is casting the numeric value to `float` and you're done, and sort as usual with `key=operator.itemgetter(1)`

```py
def calculate_sorted_averages(file1, file2):
    d = {}
    with open (r'path/to/unsorted.csv', 'r') as f1:
        reader=csv.reader(f1)
        for row in reader:
            name=row[0]
            average=row[1]
            d[name]=float(average)
    sorted_dict=OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
    with open (r'path/to/sorted.csv', 'w', newline='') as f2:
        for key in sorted_dict.keys():
            writer=csv.writer(f2)
            writer.writerow([key,sorted_dict[key]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aaa = {'0': ['mandana', 7.5], '1': ['hamid', 6.066666666666666], '2': ['sina', 11.285714285714286], '3': ['sara', 9.75],
       '4': ['soheila', 7.833333333333333], '5': ['ali', 5.0], '6': ['sarvin', 11.375]}

sorted_ = sorted(aaa.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])
sorted_ = dict(sorted_)
```

Output

```
{'5': ['ali', 5.0], '1': ['hamid', 6.066666666666666], '0': ['mandana', 7.5], '4': ['soheila', 7.833333333333333], '3': ['sara', 9.75], '2': ['sina', 11.285714285714286], '6': ['sarvin', 11.375]}
```

You didn't show the entire dictionary with the keys. So I created my 'aaa'. Sorting takes place by the second element.

Answer (score 0):

By default, text read from a file, with or without `csv.reader`, is stored into strings. You need to call `float` on the second element of each row, to interpret it as a floating-point number.

I think using an `OrderedDict` is a bit overkill here. One call to `sorted` is enough.

```py
import csv

def calculate_sorted_averages(filename_input, filename_output):
    with open(filename_input, 'r') as f1:
        reader=csv.reader(f1)
        sorted_rows = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
    with open(filename_output, 'w') as f2:
        writer = csv.writer(f2)
        writer.writerows(sorted_rows)

calculate_sorted_averages('file1.csv', 'file2.csv')
```

Results:

```
$ cat file1.csv 
mandana,7.5
hamid,6.066666666666666
sina,11.285714285714286
sara,9.75
soheila,7.833333333333333
ali,5.0
sarvin,11.375

$ cat file2.csv
ali,5.0
hamid,6.066666666666666
mandana,7.5
soheila,7.833333333333333
sara,9.75
sina,11.285714285714286
sarvin,11.375
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the `pandas` module for this.

The `pandas.read_csv()` function would read the csv file whose path you pass in as a parameter inside the function, and would convert it into a `pandas` dataframe or in simpler words it would display a table inside Python.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Python with Jadi\file1.csv")
df.columns = ["Name", "Value"]    # To set the column names. Only do this if the dataframe doesn't already have a column name.
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by = "Value")    # Sorting the dataframe by the values in the "Value" column
```

Output -

|  | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | ali | 5.0 |
| 1 | hamid | 6.066666666666666 |
| 0 | mandana | 7.5 |
| 4 | soheila | 7.833333333333333 |
| 3 | sara | 9.75 |
| 2 | sina | 11.285714285714286 |
| 6 | sarvin | 11.375 |

You can convert this dataframe back to a csv file using `to_csv()`. Pass in the file path as the parameter and set `index = False` if you don't want the index to be added as a column.

Answer (score -1):

Pandas can be used for this - you can install it with `pip install pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df.columns = ['name', 'value']
df.sort_values('value', inplace=True, ascending=True)

print(df)
```